# How to verify if a WPF window is fully visible in the screen?

Tags: wpf, testcomplete

I am working on a WPF application using TestComplete 9 (JScript). I want to verify if a popup window is fully displayed on the screen or not. How can I do that in TestComplete?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the tips from the Waiting for an Object, Process or Window Activation help topic (http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/68268/) not working for you?

Comment: They are working. But here my problem is , i have a Window of which only  half is visible in the screen.I have a button to click in the hidden part of the window.Now my script is failing saying that it cannot find the button. Would Visible or VisibleOnscreen be helpful in determining if the window is fully visible in the screen?

Comment: I bet that VisibleOnScreen should work for you. If not, it would be a good idea to contact SmartBear Support: http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete